# Why does Firefox 4 absolutely position fieldset legends differently than other browsers?

Tags: css, firefox, css-position, firefox4, legend

Why does Firefox 4 absolutely position fieldset legends differently than other browsers?

Test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            *
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            body
            {
                font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 62.5%;
            }

            #wrapper
            {
                margin: auto;
                padding: 1em;
                width: 720px;
            }

            form
            {
                width: 670px;
                padding: 25px;

                background-color: #ffffff; /* White */
                color: #000000; /* Black */

                border: 1px solid #cccccc; /* Gray */

                font-size: 12px;
            }

            fieldset
            {
                position: relative;
                border: 1px solid #cccccc; /* Gray */
                padding: 25px 10px 5px 15px;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            fieldset legend
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 5px;
                left: -10px;

                /* Firefox */
                /*top: -20px;
                left: -25px;*/

                font-weight: 900;

                background-color: #ffffff; /* White */
            }

            /* Input Types */

            label
            {
                margin-right: 10px;
                line-height: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <form method="POST" action="test" id="testForm">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Test</legend>
                    <label for="test">Test:</label><input type="text" id="test" name="test" value=""/>
                </fieldset>

                <input type="submit" value="Test"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice that in Opera 11.10 Build 2092, Chrome 11.0.696.65, Safari 5.0.4 (7533.20.27), and Windows Internet Explorer 9, they display the legend on the left, overlapping the fieldset border.

In Firefox 4.0.1, I have to change the `top` and `left` properties to get a similar effect. For example, within the `style` tag of the test page, uncomment this CSS:

```
                /* Firefox */
                /*top: -20px;
                left: -25px;*/
```

Comment: I'm sure you've noticed that Firefox 4 has a lot of difficulties and oddities. I've dropped back to 3.6.17; I'll wait for a few weeks until version 4 has settled.

Comment: @Pete FF4 was released (non-beta) on March 22. It scores 97/100 on the [Acid3 test](http://acid3.acidtests.org/) (exactly the same score as Chrome 11). What makes you think that anything's going to change in "a few weeks?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`legend` elements are quirky and weird. That being said, if *all* the other browsers do the same thing, then Firefox should do the same thing.

There's already a bug report here describing the issue in detail: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=450418

A workaround is to add a wrapper `div` inside the `fieldset` and move the `padding` to that.

**Your unchanged code:** http://jsbin.com/ivedo4

**Fixed code:** http://jsbin.com/ivedo4/2

I tested it with the same browsers (not *identical* versions, but close) you listed in your question, and the rendering was consistent.

My code doesn't look quite right in IE8, but yours is broken in exactly the same way.